# Jupyterhub on Google compute engine

Tags: ipython, google-compute-engine, python-sockets

I'm trying to set up a Jupyterhub instance to serve IPython notebooks on a Google Compute Engine. However, when running jupyterhub i am faced with an error regarding sockets:

```
[E 2015-08-31 10:27:55.617 JupyterHub app:1097]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/esten/anaconda3/envs/py3k/lib/python3.3/site-    packages/jupyterhub/app.py", line 1095, in launch_instance_async
    yield self.start()
  File "/home/esten/anaconda3/envs/py3k/lib/python3.3/site-packages/jupyterhub/app.py", line 1027, in start
    self.http_server.listen(self.hub_port, address=self.hub_ip)
  File "/home/esten/anaconda3/envs/py3k/lib/python3.3/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 126, in listen
    sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)
  File "/home/esten/anaconda3/envs/py3k/lib/python3.3/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 187, in bind_sockets
    sock.bind(sockaddr)
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

The address/port assigned by the config file is localhost/8081, and binding a socket like below works perfectly fine

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
s.bind(("localhost", 8081))
```

Does jupyterhub look somewhere else for the information or is something done differently when binding the socket through my own code?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with GCE not supporting ipv6.
I found this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jupyter/L_uc7B3sQQg) explaining that enabling ipv6 solved the issue on another machine.

Running using --ip solved the issue:

```
jupyter notebook --ip="*"
```